# Cannot get Quicktime to Play in IE 9

Tags: html, video, internet-explorer-9, html5-video, quicktime

I am trying to get a movie uploaded from a mobile device to play in a browser.
It works fine in Chrome and FF and IE9(compatibility mode) but I cannot get it to play in IE9 not in compatibility mode.

My embed code is:

```
<video id='vid' class='video' width='274' height='169' controls='controls' preload='load' autoplay='autoplay'>
  <source src='/videos/vid1.mov'  />
  <object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" width="320" height="256" >
    <param name="src" value='/videos/vid1.mov'>
    <param name="autoplay" value="true">
    <param name="loop" value="false">
    <param name="controller" value="true">
    <embed src='/videos/vid1.mov'  width="274" height="169" autoplay="true" loop="false" controller="true" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/"></embed>
  </object>
</video>
```

At first I was just trying the  Html5 embed code, but that didn't work, so switched it out for object and embed which didn't work either.
I found that I can combine both here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp
but still it doesn't work anyway.

After spending 2 hours googling and trying different variations of this I need help!

Comment: Do you have ActiveX Filtering enabled? Is your document in Standards Mode?

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea about activeX filtering and what's standards mode?

Comment: Press `Alt + V` to open your toolbar. Then view `Tools > ActiveX Filtering`. If it's checked, uncheck it. For Standards Mode, press `F12` to load up your Developer Tools, and look for "Document Mode" within the top right of those tools.

Comment: Oh actually in IE? I have checked these and they are OK but this problem is occurring in IE9 in general, so I would not be able to make all my users update their IE settings.

Comment: What were the results of those two checks? Only one of those can be controlled by you ultimately. If a user chooses to disable ActiveX Objects, you cannot control that. You can, however, control whether or not `<video>` is available to the user by being in Doc Mode IE9 Standards+.

Comment: IE9 is in standards mode.. just checked again.

Comment: I dropped this code into a new page, swapped out the video file for a local `.mp4`, and it fired right up. Without seeing the live page you're working with, I can only assume the problem is encoding, or something else on the page.

Answer (score 0):

IE9's HTML5 specs only support H.264 video encoding, so it's worth checking if the .mov was encoded properly
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/04/29/html5-video.aspx

It could also help to supply at least 2 formats of your video, as not all browsers support one particular format. Perhaps .mp4 and .mov? If you're really ambitious swap .mov with .ogv, add a flash-based fallback as your object tag and you should be pretty well set.

Comment: The movie is posted directly from an iPhone with no changes. Do you know is this the correct encoding?

Comment: Not sure, but [a quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=iphone+video+encoding) found an [article which likely has the answers you seek](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/the-complete-guide-to-ipod-video-formats-and-display-resolutions/).

Answer (score 0):

**change the mime type (as the server delivers it to the browser) from video/quicktime to video/mp4**. Simplest way to do this, would be to add this to your .htaccess file:

```
AddType video/mp4 .mov
```

Everything should be good once you have this in place. The only other thing you'll likely see is videos coming from an iPhone being rotated 90 degrees to the left. This is the raw format stored by iOS. You'll have to take care of that on the iPhone or the server